# Can't remove scrollbar in PS3 NetFront browser

Tags: cross-browser, cross-platform, playstation3

I can't remove the vertical scrollbar in PS3 NetFront browser. Even where there is no content in the page, a greyed out scrollbar still appears.  I have tried messing around with the overflow property but I've had no luck.

There's not much info out there for developing a site for PS3/Netfront. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, putting a scroll="no" on the body tag seems to work.